# What stage does magento exactly send the "email copy of invoice"?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, invoice, pdf, create-invoice

I would like to know at what stage in the invoicing process of magento does it send the the invoice email that it sends when you click the **"email copy of invoice "**? and hit **"submit invoice"**?

I have heard mixed information, with some suggesting the email is sent before the creation of the invoice.

I believe that the email is sent once an invoice is created and saved in the database/model.

If anyone would be able to explain this to myself I would thoroughly appreciate it.

[image: checkbox screengrab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this in action inside `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController` class in Magento. Take a look at `saveAction` inside that class. Sending email is the last step of the process, after Magento has saved the invoice in Database.

Comment: Would you be able to expand as to why when clicking email copy of invoice checkbox it creates the order pdf rather than the invoice pdf ?